# Generate Junit Test report while using Uiautomatorviewer in android

Tags: android, junit, android-uiautomator

While running the UiAutomator the result is shown on the command prompt with failure and pass trace. Is there any possibility to generate any XML report using Uiautomator.
If possible please let me know your suggestions

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What do you mean by a XML report? Please be more specific. BTW - duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20008282/how-to-get-xml-report-from-android-uiautomator

Comment: I mean output in the standard XML format, Like XML report which is  obtained using the robotium tool along side with eclipse IDE.

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same problem and was able to solve it with [automator-log-converter](https://github.com/dpreussler/automator-log-converter)

Comment: Hi Kristiina, Thanks for your response it was very useful

Answer (score 0):

It might be late to answer this question. For others reference, the `connectedCheck` Gradle task executes instrumentation tests located in androidTest sourceset, and iterate over all compatible running emulators and connected devices that are already running to install and run the tests. This includes the testing with Espresso and UIAutomator.

The raw test results, in XML format, will be written to 'build/outputs/androidTest-results/connected'. And a more organised report, in HTML format, is wrote to 'build/outputs/androidTest/connected' with an index.html file serving as the entry point.

You may find it within the Gradle tool window in the Android Studio as shown in the screenshot below:

[image: Gradle tool window]